# Separate apps for InTune-enabled version, or optional integration within one app?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, intune

We have an enterprise-centric app in the iTunes App Store (iOS) and Google Play Store (Android).

A large customer is requesting InTune SDK integration, but not all of our customers use InTune.

Several high volume apps offer separate versions for regular and InTune-enabled deployment e.g. "Adobe Acrobat Reader" app vs. "Adobe Acrobat Reader for Microsoft InTune".

Are these separate apps are a result of a technical limitation (e.g. inability to deactivate InTune integration when not required), or is it purely a product decision, to have a dedicated app for this purpose?

Is it possible to integrate the InTune SDK into an app and only enable it when required? How would one go about this if so?

Or does InTune become so baked-into an app that it becomes impossible to run it outside an InTune deployment, even when not required?